# Why git is Ignoring my .gitignore File and not hiding the folder when commit?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJieL.png)

```
First Image On vscode when I've included the file in .gitignore File.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umFnX.png)

```
Second Image on Github.When pushed the code in GitHub, though the files are displaying.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miknV.png)

```
included folder and files in the .gitignore file.
```

**Is git is ignoring my .gitignore file?
If it is can someone tell me the solution?
How to fix it**
**Any sort of Help will be helpful. Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the folder/files is already committed to the repository. If it is, you'll need to remove them first.

Also check if you have global gitignore interfering with the repo.